# Sort a DataFrame column based on duplicates in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following one :

```py
     'A'     'B'     'C'     'D'    
1    4      1      'af23'      'z'
2    4      3      'bf14'      'y'
3    4      2      'bf14'      'x'
4    6      4      'cf51'      'w'
5    6      5      'ch63'      'v'
6    5      6      'cm79'      'u'
```

When I sort using the following code :

```py
df=df.sort_values(by=['A', 'C']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**I get :**

```py
     'A'     'B'     'C'     'D'    
1    4      1      'af23'      'z'
2    4      3      'bf14'      'y'
3    4      2      'bf14'      'x'
4    5      6      'cm79'      'u'
5    6      4      'cf51'      'w'
6    6      5      'ch63'      'v'
```

As you can see there is no permutation between df['B'][2] and df['B'][3] given that df['C'][2] and df['C'][3] are duplicates

The result I am seeking for is to sort df based on 'A' and 'C' including sorting values of 'B' when corresponding values in 'C' are equal

**Goal**
Is to get the following df after sorting by column 'A' and column 'C'

```py
     'A'     'B'     'C'     'D'    
1    4      1      'af23'      'z'
2    4      2      'bf14'      'x'
3    4      3      'bf14'      'y'
4    5      6      'cm79'      'u'
5    6      4      'cf51'      'w'
6    6      5      'ch63'      'v'
```

Comment: There can be problem in your pandas version, as I have checked it in colab and it is working fine.

Comment: I just checked it in VScode - and got expected result using code provided. ie. not seeing the issue described.  (am using pandas version 1.4.4)

Comment: @PrakashDahal , Please take a look at the new edits of my question

Comment: @ScottC , Please take a look at the new edits of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
df=df.sort_values(by=['A', 'C','D']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
'''
    A   B   C       D
0   4   1   af23    z
1   4   2   bf14    x
2   4   3   bf14    y
3   5   6   cm79    u
4   6   4   cf51    w
5   6   5   ch63    v


'''
```

Comment: Let's assume column 'D' doesn't exist, is there another way to solve this? @Clegane

Comment: Yes. You can use `df=df.sort_values(by=['A', 'C','B']).reset_index(drop=True)`